# VIM search and replace regex

Tags: regex, vim, pcre

What's the best way in VIM using search and replace to add the number 1 after every FIRST comma on a line? Each line has multiple commas (this is a csv), I want to insert the value 1 though after the first comma on each line.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe just `:s/,/,1/` should do it. If you don't use the `g` option, it will only replace the first instance found per line.

Do `:%s/,/,1/` if you want it to apply to the entire file, the first option only does it for a single line.

Comment: I actually experienced in my vim on Mac OSX Mountain Lion that OMITTING the /g option was the only way to replace multiple occurrences of the regex on the same line, which is pretty strange. The /g option is not working as it is supposed to. Removing /g allowed me to search and replace multiple instances of the match per line.

Answer (score 1):

Use this regex `/(^.*?,)/gm` with this replace `$11`.  For each line, from the start of the line it captures everything up to the first comma.  This is captured in group 1 denoted by `$1`.  Replace it with `$11` which is group 1 followed by a number `1`.

Check here: http://regexr.com?30pjf